# ¿como maximizar la ventana principal al ejecutar el codigo con la libreria customtkinter?

Tags: python

Al ejecutar mi código con la libreria **CustomTkinter** sale la ventana con sus dimensiones predeterminadas, intento como si fuera con la libreria Tkinter pero no funciona. Ya intente con el atributo -fullscreen, pero no me sirve porque no se muestra la barra de herramientas de la ventana, tales como: cerra, minimizar y minimizar tamaño.

```
import tkinter as tk 
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import ttk

#Estilizar ventana login
ctk.set_appearance_mode('dark')
#Crear ventana Login    
root = ctk.CTk()

root.title('MyBasicContar')
root.geometry('800x600')
root.attributes('-fullscreen')

root.mainloop()`
```

Comment: Sin código a la vista es imposible responder. Además necesitas explicar que es eso de * intento como si fuera con la libreria Tkinter pero no funciona* ¿Qué intentaste? ¿Cómo resultó? -- Puedes editar la pregunta para agregar el código como texto y otra información relevante.

Comment: Hola DiMA, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Podés usar root.state("zoomed"), pero solo funciona en Wndows.